# Constructing a tree in Latex using tikz

Tags: tikz-trees

[image]

[image]

I'm trying to do this one, but I have no idea how to do the overlapping lines, or the second image.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={draw, circle}, -]
    \node {A}
    child {node {B}}
    child {node {C}}
    child {node {D}}
    child {node {E}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This is my starting code. I'm still trying to figure it out. Unfortunately, I'm new to tex, so it is taking time for me to get it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us the TeX code you have tried so far ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

welcome! I'm also new to TeX and I've been using this document: [https://www.sfu.ca/~haiyunc/notes/Game_Trees_with_TikZ.pdf](https://www.sfu.ca/%7Ehaiyunc/notes/Game_Trees_with_TikZ.pdf) to help me draw some game trees for a project.

I've attempted to recreate your drawing in overleaf and this is what I came up with:
[image: Game theory tree]

I drew this using the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\RequirePackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{3pt}%

\title{Stack OverFlow Game Tree Question}
\author{Cassie}
\date{October 2021}

\begin{document}

% Node styles
\tikzset{
% Two node styles for game trees: solid and hollow
solid node/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1.5,fill=black},
hollow node/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1.5}
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=7,font=\footnotesize]
% Specify spacing for each level of the tree
\tikzstyle{level 1}=[level distance=5mm,sibling distance=5mm]
\tikzstyle{level 2}=[level distance=5mm,sibling distance=5mm]
% The Tree
\node(0)[hollow node]{A}
child{node(1)[hollow node]{B}
edge from parent node[left]{}
}
child{node(2)[hollow node]{C}
edge from parent node[right]{}
}
child{node(3)[hollow node]{D}
edge from parent node[right]{}
}
child{node(4)[hollow node]{E}
edge from parent node[right]{}
};

% draw lines
\draw[solid](1)to(2);
\draw[solid,bend right](2)to(4);
\draw[solid,bend right](1)to(3);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I hope this helps and good luck!

Comment: This will be a good starting point in recreating the other trees I have been working on. Thank you and for sharing the link as well.

Answer (score 2):

Your tree can be simply drawn by use of the `forest` package (which is based on `tikz` package). With it the code is significantly shorter:

```
\documentclass[margin=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}


\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
for tree = {
% nodes
    circle, draw, minimum size=1.2em, inner sep=2pt,
% tree styles
    s sep=6mm,
    l sep=9mm
            }
[A
    [B, name=b]
    [C, name=c]
    [D, name=d]
    [E, name=e]
]
% lines between nodes in the same level
\draw   (b) to [bend right] (d)
        (c) to [bend right] (e);
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This one is much easier to understand!

Answer (score 1):

This is not a game tree, but you can also use the [`istgame`](https://ctan.org/pkg/istgame) package to draw the graph.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
    
\usepackage{istgame}

\begin{document}

\begin{istgame}
\setistNewNodeStyle{ellipse node}[minimum size=2em]
\setxtinfosetstyle{thin,solid}
\setistmathTF*011<sffamily>

\istrooto(0){A}
  \istb
  \istbA(1.3)
  \istbA(1.6)
  \istb
  \endist
\istrooto(1)(0-1){B} \endist
\istrooto(2)(0-2){C} \endist
\istrooto(3)(0-3){D} \endist
\istrooto(4)(0-4){E} \endist
\xtInfoset(1)(2)
\xtInfoset(2)(4)
\xtCInfoset(3)(1)<1.5>
\end{istgame}

\end{document}
```

[enter link description here](https://ctan.org/pkg/istgame)

Comment: I approved always your nice package :-)